# Group by counts of values not available at a point in time

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I have a situation where I want to return results for a `count(*)` `group by` on fixed number of values for a given column, even though the column values may not be there at a given point in time in that case it would return zero.

Example:

```
select code, status, status_desc, count(*)
from table group by code, status, status_desc;
```

returns the following counts:

[image: ![enter image description here]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RTQPB.jpg)

Now status can take on the values 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 at any given point in time.
How can I get the result-set to display those as well with their counts as zero so that my result-set always returns 7 rows with counts of each status even if its null at that time for each code.

This is an oracle 11g DB.

Comment: Does that select - without a GROUP BY - really work? (It's invalid SQL...)

Comment: sorry the group by got edited in my edit ! lol it does have a group by let me add it in

Comment: @Lola_B, I've posted a better answer. Try it when you can

Answer (score 0):

You can try this one at any given point in time :)

```
   select * from (select status status, count(*) from your_table group by status union all
   select stat status, 0 from (select level stat from dual connect by level <=7) where stat not in(select status from your_table)) order by status
```

Comment: thanks Vance. But this doesnt hep in getting me the code as I can't nvl it to a standard code. It must return 7 statuses for each code.

Comment: let me try the new answer!